# Good colorings in a sphere

Tags: combinatorics

Given a sphere, a great circle of the sphere is a circle on the sphere whose diameter
is also a diameter of the sphere. For a given positive integer $n$, the surface of a sphere is divided into several regions by $n$ great circles, and each region is colored black or white. We say that a coloring is good if any two adjacent regions (that share an arc as boundary, not just a finite number of points) have different colors. Find, with proof, all positive integers $n$ such that in every good coloring with $n$ great circles, the sum of the areas of the black regions is equal to the sum of the areas of the white regions.

Does anyone have any idea at all on how to start on this?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding things, as stated, the statement is false. Consider the case of two great circles  with arbitrarily small angle $\theta$ between them. One color's region will have total area $4θr^2$, which can be made arbitrarily small. Maybe the statement is true for an odd number of great circles?

Comment: The exact same question was asked in the last month. Where is this from?

Comment: @CoolMath200 You're right. Sorry, I misread your question as saying that the statement was true for every $n$. I have edited my answer to give a disproof for even $n$.$\tag*{}$ Also, I got $4\theta r^2$ by noting that the surface area of a sphere is $A=4\pi r^2$ and the proportion of the sphere covered by the two regions with angle $\theta$ is $\frac{\theta}{\pi}$. I have given my new argument in terms of proportion of the sphere's area, so that this is no longer a concern.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, particularly after it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that black and white are guaranteed to cover the same surface area precisely when $n$ is odd. The proof is actually quite simple.

Suppose $n$ is odd. Let $x$ be an arbitrary point on the sphere that is not directly on any of the great circles. Let $y$ be the antipodal point of $x$. Notice that $x$ and $y$ lie on opposing sides of each of the great circles. Therefore, if we were to draw any straight path from $x$ to $y$ (that does not pass through the intersection point of any two great circles), the path would need to pass through the boundary of each of the $n$ of the great circles exactly once, and thus change color exactly $n$ (which is an odd number) times. This implies that $x$ will be the opposite color of $y$.

In other words, we have proven that every point on the sphere will have an antipodal point of opposite color. This is enough to show that each color will cover precisely half the surface area of the sphere.

Now, suppose $n$ is even. We may place $n$  great circles so that they all intersect at $2$ antipodal points, and the angle between any $2$ "adjacent" circles corresponding to a black section is $\theta$. In this configuration, the proportion of the sphere that black covers is precisely $\frac{n\theta}{2\pi}$, which can be made to be arbitrarily small, so that black cannot cover half the sphere.